# Android - User one time registration when they open app, then they stay logged in

Tags: android, mysql

I'm new to StackOverflow so hey! Basically I'm making an android app and I want the user to have to register first by providing some information to build a profile. These then need to be stored. But the next time they open the app, they'll go to the main menu.I'm new to Android so please please help me :)

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that will run only when the app is first opened, but I'll leave requesting and saving the info you want up to you.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
       first=settings.getString("first","notSet");

       if (first.equals("notSet")) { 
              //Code in here will be executed only at initial start up. 
       }
```